# How to separate view model from elements defined in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, telerik

I have a Telerik RadGridView that I need to call CommitEdit() on. Currently I am calling it with the following code from the viewmodel.

```
  ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Container.View.RadGrid.CommitEdit();
```

But I have found this prevents me from being able to unit test the viewmodel. How can I separate the viewmodel from the view in a case such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to decouple "UI" specific functionality from the ViewModel, what you can do is add an event to your ViewModel that you will call whenever you need to commit an edit. Something like:

```
public ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public event Action CommitEdit;
}
```

then, in your code behind, subscribe to that event:

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataContext = DataContext as IViewModel;
    if (dataContext != null)
    {
        dataContext.CommitEdit += (()=>{ Container.View.RadGrid.CommitEdit(); })
    }
}
```

Now, when you do unit tests, you can just unit test the ViewModel directly without depending on your RadGrid. This will allow to test to see if the event Action gets called.